# Ruby on Rails: Syntax within CSS in view?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it possible to integrate dynamic background in view?

```
<div style="background-image:url(rvr.profile_pic_url(:avatar).to_s)">
```

I'm not getting this correctly... i tried googling, but nothing pops up. This might be simple?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an erb tag in there instead:

```
<div style="background-image:url(<%= rvr.profile_pic_url(:avatar).to_s %>)">
```